# Are behave and behoove related?

Tags: etymology

I was pondering the etymology of behoove before actually looking it up, and noticed that behave looks and feels similar, but when I compared them while It said that behoove comes from OE, behave only showed up in the 15th century.

Is there a derivation?

Comment: Please show your research, and point out the assertions you are querying.

Answer (score 2):

It does appear that they both may have evolved from their German ancestors:

> #### Behave
>
> - early 15c., from ***[be-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be-&allowed_in_frame=0)*** intensive prefix + ***[have](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=have&allowed_in_frame=0)*** in sense of "to have or bear (oneself) in a particular way, comport" (compare German *sich behaben*, French *se porter*).
>
> Cognate Old English compound *behabban* meant "to contain," and alternatively the modern sense of *behave* might have evolved from *behabban* via a notion of "self-restraint." Related: *Behaved; behaving.*

[Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=behave&allowed_in_frame=0)

> #### Behoove
>
> - Old English *behofian* "to have need of, have use for," verbal form of the ancient compound word represented by ***[behoof](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=behoof&allowed_in_frame=0)***.
>
> Historically, it rimes with *move, prove*, but being now mainly a literary word, it is generally made to rime with *rove, grove*, by those who know it only in books.

[Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=behoove&allowed_in_frame=0)

> #### Behoof
>
> - c. 1200, "use, benefit, advantage;" Old English had *bihoflic* "useful," implying *bihof* "advantage, utility;" from Proto-Germanic *bi-hof* "that which binds, requirement, obligation" (source also of Old Frisian *bihof* "advantage," Dutch *behoef*, Middle High German *bihuof* "useful thing," German *Behuf* "benefit, use, advantage").
>
> In the common Germanic compound, the first element, likely intensive, is cognate with ***[be-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be-&allowed_in_frame=0)*** and the second with Old English *hof*, past tense of *hebban* "to raise" (see heave (v.)). The original sense is perhaps, then, "taking up (for oneself)."

[Etymon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=behoof&allowed_in_frame=0)